# What's the English equivalent for the Indonesian old saying, "a grill that is far from the fire"?

Tags: translation, proverbs

***Jauh panggang dari api*** in English is *a grill that is far from the fire* (it's a rough translation). This proverb refers to **reality that doesn't fit what you've hoped** or **a result that doesn't fit what you've done**. Or simply **you don't get what you want**.

Let's say that you've just moved to the states. You hoped that you can change your life entirely in this land of opportunity. But when you arrived there.. You were disappointed because you don't get what you expected. That's why you say, "God, **the grill is far from the fire**"

Or maybe you are a researcher and trying to find an answer or solutions for your research and problems. After many scientific methods that you've done, you haven't get the answer that can satisfy you. So you say, "**The grill is far from the fire**".

Or when something theoretically true, but in the reality isn't. So that the grill is far from the fire.

This proverb applies to situations where you feel *disappointed* because you expected more. Now, is there any English equivalent for this proverb?

Comment: A couple, not really close: We're still out in left field.  We're still at ground zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may use the idiomatic expression; *fall short of expectations*:

***[Fall short of](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/fall-short-of-something)*** (something):

> - to be less than the amount or standard that is needed or that you want

(Longman Dictionary)

- Life in NYC fell short of my expectations.
- My scientific research fell short of expectations.

Comment: So when you date someone and she isn't as what you've expected, you'd say "*She fell of my expectations*", right?

Comment: @IvanDi- would you say in Indonesian. "she is a grill that is far from the  fire"?

Comment: Nah.. I'll just say, "The grill is far from the fire". As I said in the question, it's roughly translated.

Comment: Fall short of expectations may be applied to all situations where you feel somehow "disappointed" because you expected more.

Comment: @IvanDi - Another useful expression is : ***to live up to someone's expectations***  as in: *I thought the movie was going to be better than that. It totally didn’t live up to my expectations*.  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to%20live%20up%20to%20someone's%20expectations- "

Comment: Informally, there's "close, but no cigar" and "a day late and a dollar short."  Nothing as marvelous as a grill too far from the fire.

Comment: By the way, what tense should I use if I'm asking? I mean, "*Did I live up your expectations?*" or "*Do I live up your expectations*"